# Free applications for learning English on Windows Phone

Tags: gratis, windows-phone, dictionary

I need Android FunEasyLearn (e.g. “Learn English 6000 Words”) analog (or Anki analog) for Windows Phone.

1. Basicly I want program with English dictionary (for learning English) for Russian users. But I want to learn Spanish too.
2. I want opensource or free program, but with dictionary included already. I don't want to create full own dictionary, but ability for adding new words is welcome. If program is without dictionary included, then it will be good if program will use GoldenDict dictionaries:

   - StarDict (.ifo/.dict./.idx/.syn)
   - ABBYY Lingvo .dsl dictionary files
   - Babylon (.bgl) dictionaries
   - XDXF dictionary
   - Dictd (.index / .dict / .dz) dictionary files
3. I want to learn random words (or in game format), and I don't want to typing words in dictionary search by myself (like in GoldenDict).